# python how to check if a module exists without importing it

Tags: python, import, module

I need to check if module exists (without checking if their import modules exists), import the module to check if it exists is a bad idea because:

**foo/module_A.py:**

```
import invalid_module_asdfghjkl


class ClassA:
    pass
```

**foo/module_B.py:**

```
try:
    __import__('foo.module_A')
except ImportError, e:
    >>> No module named invalid_module_asdfghjkl
```

So, **My module exists**, but not one of their imported modules, how can I check IF MY MODULE EXISTS when it has invalid imports?

Comment: Have you looked at [`imp.find_module`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/imp.html#imp.find_module)?

Comment: The name of your module will be in the error message if it's the one that can't be found, otherwise it's something else you're importing from there.

Comment: @BrenBarn, find_module crashes too because internally performs an import